# Retrieving sets of covarying variables

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation, variable-names

I have a data frame with a large number of variables represented as columns that vary with time as an index for them. I would like to retrieve sets of highly covarying variables.

```
data <- data.frame(time_series=c(1,2,3), 
                           score1=c(0.5, 0.4, 0.6), 
                           score2=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1), 
                           score3=c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5), 
                           score4=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.4), 
                           score5=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2))
```

Two functions that should give identical results are,

```
library(stats)
#autocorrelation function with lag 0 over a data frame
acf_results <- acf(data[2:length(names(data))], plot = FALSE, lag.max = 0)

#simple Pearson correlation function.
cor_results <- cor(data[2:length(names(data))], method = "pearson")
```

It would be possible to filter the results with a simple `(X_results > 0.6)`, but this seems to lose the names of the variables.

I am trying to extract the sets of variables that covary to a threshold from a large dataframe. I would expect that I am missing some simple built-in functions. Any advice on how this could be done?

Edit: I realized Spearman would be an absolutely wrong function for this, as it would rank the values too, not just the time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
cor_results <- cor(data[2:length(names(data))], method = "spearman")
x <- which(cor_results > 0.6, arr.ind=TRUE)
x
#        row col
# score1   1   1
# score5   5   1
# score2   2   2
# score3   3   3
# score5   5   3
# score4   4   4
# score1   1   5
# score3   3   5
# score5   5   5
```

to get a matrix of indices of the cells meeting your requirements. To make this a bit more readable you might want to do

```
x[] <- colnames(cor_results)[x]
rownames(x) <- NULL
x
      row      col     
# [1,] "score1" "score1"
# [2,] "score5" "score1"
# [3,] "score2" "score2"
# [4,] "score3" "score3"
# [5,] "score5" "score3"
# [6,] "score4" "score4"
# [7,] "score1" "score5"
# [8,] "score3" "score5"
# [9,] "score5" "score5"
```